# Is there a linux command to bulk optimize several image files in just one step?

Tags: command-line, image-processing

I have a bunch of images in a folder:

```
images/image1.jpg
images/image2.jpg
...
```

These images are not optimized for the web.

Just wondering if is there a linux command to bulk optimize those images in just one step?

**UPDATE**: I need to do two thing for each image:

1. if the width of the image is higher than 900px then reduce the width to 900px (keeping the proportions)
2. save the file with a lower quality, let's says 70% of the original.

Comment: There is [imagemagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). It's a program, rather then a "linux command", but should work just as well.

Answer (score 4):

Install [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/):

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

And use the `convert` command as follows:

```
mkdir new
for file in images/*jpg
do convert -quality 70% -resize '>900x' "$file" new/$(basename "$file")
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a whole lot of files, and want to get this done quickly, you can also use the parallel program:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick parallel
```

And then the following:

```
find . \( -name '*.jp*g' -o -name '*.png' \) -a ! -name '*.min.*' -type f -print0 | \
parallel -0 'convert {} -resize '>900x' -quality '70%' \
    -set filename:newname "%d/%[basename].min.%[extension]" "%[filename:newname]"'
```

Let's walk through that:

- `find` -- look for files

  - `.` -- in the current directory
  - `\( -name '*.jp*g' -o -name '*.png' \)` -- that are either png or jpeg (both "jpg" and "jpeg" are common extensions!)
  - `-a ! -name '*.min.*'` -- and skip files that are already minimized
  - `-type f` -- and are actual files, not symlinks or oddly-named directories
  - `-print0` -- print these files separated with the null byte (so that spaces don't break things)
- `parallel` -- read from the previous command and execute this command in parallel for each element

  - `-0` -- each element is separated with the null byte
  - `convert {}` -- call the imagemagick "convert" program with the filename substituted for `{}`

    - `resize '>900x' -quality '70%'` -- resize the image to a max of 900px on the x axis and change the jpeg quality to 70%. [There are *many* other possible options here.](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#option)
    - `-set filename:newname "%d/%[basename].min.%[extension]"` -- create a variable with the new filename. [See the docs for all valid values](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php).

      - `%d` -- the directory that the file is in
      - `%[basename]` -- the filename without any extensions
      - `%[extension]` -- the file's original extension
    - `"%[filename:newname]"` -- the output filename we set up in the previous step